# Using jquery to get dimensions of hidden elements. 

Tags: jquery, dimensions

This is a common question but I have a slight twist to it so hopefully it's not a duplicate:

I have a situation where I need to trigger `.show()` on elements that are rendered with `display: none` on page load. In ideal situations, I show everything on a page, then hide what needs to be hidden. Most clients hate the 'flash' of rendering, though, so they usually balk at that.

What I need to do now is grab the width of the element that is set to display: none; There are lots of ways to do this but traditionally have been a bit hacky such as 'clone the html, set to block, do your calculations, remove clone' type things.

The 'twist' to the question is: are there newer/better/default standard ways to do this with the more recent versions of jQuery (1.6.*)? Or do we still revert to rolling our own workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some situations, you can set to position: absolute, visibility: hidden, display: block to cause it to have it's proper size (though not constrained by anything around it because it's been removed from the layout), but not be visible and not affect the layout of the page.  Then, set back to display: none, position: static and visibility: visible to put it back the way it was.

Comment: still seems hacky but will give it a shot! Why static instead of relative for the position though?

Comment: `static` is the default value for `position`, and it is different from `relative` in some subtle and important ways - child nodes with `position: absolute` are relative to the first ancestor having `position: [relative,absolute]`, relative positioning can trigger some pretty terrible bugs in IE, and the top/left/bottom/right css parameters will apply (amongst other things)

Comment: @digitalbath: I'm not sure what the point of your comment was.  The point of mine was that an object that is position: absolute, display: block and visibility: hidden will not be visible, but will be laid out by the browser to have it's natural size.  There are some situations where this is useful to find out an objects laid out size without ever making it visible.

Comment: @jfriend00, I was responding to @DA's comment.

Comment: @digitalbath: I see.  @DA: My use of position: static was just to restore the object to whatever it was originally.

Comment: This works great. Almost so great that you'd think maybe they'd just roll this into jQuery's 'width' and 'height' methods.

Comment: I actually think it is in jQuery somewhere (I've seen it somewhere), but I don't know where.

Answer (score 1):

Usually if you set a default height-width in a css file you should be able to get the width/height of an hidden element.

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/qyJjh/

Comment: I need the opposite...finding the width of something I haven't set.

Comment: Just set the width in the css like i did for the height http://jsfiddle.net/qyJjh/1/

Comment: I can't set the width. I'm setting it dynamically based on various other widths. So I can't preset it. This is a mobile app and we're dealing with a wide range of screen resolutions--hence the attempt to set widths dynamically via JS rather than via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I would just show the element with negative margins such as -99999px, absolutely positioned to avoid breaking the layout. Then you can show it and get width and height, I don't think this is particularly hacky to do if you do it this way.

Comment: I would also try with opacity:0 (and various cross-browser alternatives), or negative z-index... never tried that.

Comment: Anyway I tried getting the size of a display:none element with jQuery and it works ok in all browsers... http://jsfiddle.net/sJL6T/9/

Comment: That does work, though the challenge is if you need to get the size of child elements: http://jsfiddle.net/sJL6T/10/

Comment: Then I would just show the parent and hide it again when you're done. http://jsfiddle.net/sJL6T/28/

Comment: yes, that's always been my preferred method. It sometimes causes a 'flash of rendering' on slower devices though.